# Why is a function not serializable?

Tags: javascript, function, serialization, meteor, argument-passing

### Background

In the Meteor docs for [`Meteor.call()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call), it reads:

> If you include a callback function as the last argument (which can't be an argument to the method, since functions aren't serializable)...

I have ran something similar to `Meteor.call('name', function() {console.log('abc');}, function() {})` before, where `function() {console.log('abc');}` is passed in as an ***argument***, and the empty `function() {}` is used as a stub for the asynchronous callback. *And it works.*

So is that statement telling me I shouldn't pass ***any*** functions as arguments to functions, or only applies for callback functions.

### Question

In either case, why is that function not serializable? My shallow understanding is only that a serializable object is one where you can turn it into a sequence of bits (`1`'s and `0`'s), and since *everything* digital are sequence of bits, I don't understand why functions are not serializable.

I found some [explanations](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1424#c3), but they are all related to Java, and for someone who doesn't already know the significance of serialization, it's not much help.

**Why is a function not serializable?** (and how does it relate to `Meteor.call()`?)

Comment: I think that bit of Meteor documentation could be explained better.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and answer, they've ***all*** helped me (can't always say this). Sorry I couldn't accept all of them!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most cases, serializable means that you can convert something into a language-agnostic representation and reconstruct the original state somewhere else. E.g. the array `[0,1,2]` could be serialized to JSON `"[0,1,2]"` and deserialized somewhere else.

> In either case, why is that function not serializable?

A function object (in JS) consist of two parts: its body (code) and the environment it is defined in. Every function is a closure. Getting the source of the function is easy, but you can't get the state of its environment.

Example:

```
var foo = 42;
function bar() {
    console.log(foo);
}

thirdService(bar);
```

`thirdService` has no idea about the environment the function is defined in. All it can do is get a string representation of the body of the function, but it doesn't know the value of `foo`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if I pass a function in that doesn't depend on the environment (say, all it does is `console.log('abc');`), then *that* function can be seen as serializable?

Comment: @dayuloli no no; *no* function is serializable as JSON. It's simply not part of what JSON is intended to do. JSON is *purely* a data interchange language, intended to be language-neutral.

Comment: @dayuloli see my answer; I think you misinterpreted the sense of that statement in the Meteor documentation. What it was trying to explain was how the arguments to `Meteor.call()` are interpreted by the library, and it really doesn't have much to do with the topic of function serialization.

Comment: @dayuloli: Not as JSON, but you can have your own format. If you only have JS-to-JS communication, then you can get away with converting the function to a string and `eval`uating it. But if you communicate between languages, it's more difficult (maybe impossible, how would you deserialize a JS function to a Python function?).

Comment: Thank you both for your time and patience! I understand it a lot more now. A major reason to serialize parameters is for communication between functions (or langauges, or environments), but functions cannot be serialized, at least not in JSON. But the statement in the Meteor docs had nothing to do with serialization *per se*, but more to do with how Meteor decide what is callback, and what is an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this comes down to the format that things are serialized in. In general use pretty much every example I've come across uses JSON to serialize Javascript objects, and simply put JSON doesn't support a `function` data type.

If you look at [json.org](http://www.json.org/) you can see the support data types. You can see the different values supported in the diagram below taken from the same site:

[image]

The nearest you can get to a function is expressing it as a string, but then during deserialization there's nothing to inform you how to re-hydrate this back to a Javascript function.

Comment: So you're saying that functions *are* serializable, just not in the formats supported by the language/framework. And we can use another serializer to serialized the function into 0's and 1's (or something other than JSON, which somehow does support functions), but it won't be of much use to any language. Hitting any nails here?

Comment: Yes I believe so - I'm not quite sure what happens if you try to `JSON.stringify` a function. I happened to need to do something similar and had to manually re-create a function from a string basically using `eval`

Answer (score 2):

Take the case of the following object

```
var aFancyValue = 123;
var obj = {
   propName: "A value"
   funcName: function(){
      // you do something fancy with aFancyName variable
   }
}
```

Now when you try to serialize `obj`, and if functions were to be serializable, then `aFancyValue` should some how be present other wise the function won't work.

The other things such as properties are literals and they don't rely on anything else. They are complete by themselves, but functions *might* are not like that as they might be depending on the data, which might not be accessed when it is serialized.

**In short**, the environment, context of functions is not known, which is why they can't be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

What the Meteor documentation means by that statement is that the API (`Meteor.call`) can tell that you're passing a callback as the last argument because it knows that a parameter that's a function *can't* be one of the parameters to be passed to the server, because those have to be serializable as JSON.

So: when you use `Meteor.call()` to invoke a method, the first parameter is the name of the method to call. Then come zero or more parameters to pass to the method, and each of those must be representable as JSON. Finally, if you want an asynchronous callback, you pass that as the last argument.

Contrast that with `Meteor.apply()`, which does the same thing but takes *three* arguments: the method name, an array of parameter values, and the (optional) callback. Because all of the method parameters are in the array, it doesn't need to do any "sniffing" to decide whether there's a callback parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, now I understand more the difference between `Meteor.call()` and `Meteor.apply()`