# Why doesn't structuredClone copy Function Object?

Tags: javascript

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone) says that "**Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to throws a DataCloneError exception**."

Why does copying a function object emit an error with [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)?

Comment: What are you looking for? Probably the only answer you can get is "That's just how JavaScript works" with a reference to the ECMAScript spec.

Comment: @Samathingamajig I want to know what potential problems are there when copying a function. I believe that there is a clear reason why structured clones do not copy functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read on [MDN/structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), it says

> ### Exceptions
>
> `DataCloneError` [`DOMException`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException)
>
> - Thrown if any part of the input value is not serializable.

For why functions are not serializable, see here: [Why is a function not serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27926619/12101554)

From what I understand of those answers, the TL;DR is that it's because a function can be converted to a string, but the variables/functions referenced in the function that are out of scope would cause issues.